# How to apply a function to groupby method in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this.

| Company | Type | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | D | 15 |
| First | D | 30 |
| First | C | 40 |
| Second | D | 10 |
| Second | C | 12 |
| Second | C | 15 |

I want to create a function that adds balance if the type is C and subtract balance if the type is D. How can I do it in the pandas groupby method using apply function?

My output should be like this:

| Company | Type | Balance | New Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | D | 15 | -15 |
| First | D | 30 | -45 |
| First | C | 40 | -5 |
| Second | D | 10 | -10 |
| Second | C | 12 | 2 |
| Second | C | 15 | 17 |

Comment: How to proceed with the first row? And what did you try so for? I presume you'll need [window function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html)

Comment: Why Balance is different from your input dataframe and your output dataframe?

Comment: Hey, It was a mistake. I changed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where`:

```
df['New Balance'] = df['Balance'].where(df['Type'] != 'D', df['Balance']*-1) \
                                 .groupby(df['Company']).cumsum()
print(df)

# Output
  Company Type  Balance  New Balance
0   First    D       15          -15
1   First    D       30          -45
2   First    C       40           -5
3  Second    D       10          -10
4  Second    C       12            2
5  Second    C       15           17
```

Comment: I changed the Balance input to clarify my point. I want to run this logic for each company separately. In your case it took new balance from First company. I don't want that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to `Company` column. I fixed my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
temp = df['type']=='c'
df['new'] = temp.replace(False, -1).replace(True, 1)*df['bal']
df.groupby('company')['new'].cumsum()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Hey, I want to group by the Company. So the logic should be work separately for each company. The first row of the Second company balance is 10, As it is D, our final output will be -10. Your code takes value from First Company.